# How to use between when comparing dateTime values saved as varchar using Spring Data and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a database with "time" column of type varchar..I'm using Spring Data and Hibernate to query the database and want to get only records between startTime and endTime.

I am using

```
tableName.findByTypeIdAndTimeBetweenOrderByTimeDesc(typeId, startTimeString, endTimeString);
```

I tried to give startTime and endTime as joda.DateTime but then I got an exception since Hibernate/Spring Data was expecting a string..any ideas how to solve this? I thought as workaround to read e.g. 200 records and than in java convert it to dateTime and compare it, but I guess there should be a more elegant solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

Since you use String to store a Timestamp unfortunately there are not much elegant solutions.

Either change the data type to Timestamp or Integer (If you want to store milliseconds)

Or Do it in your application end as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..and sorry, I didnt express myself well. I use Spring only to read the data from the db..the values from the db are imported from some other source and I cant change anything..so I have to do the workaround at the application level :/

Comment: The problem was that jdts driver was interpreting datetime2 column as varchar. I changed to ms jdbc driver and it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that jdts driver was interpreting datetime2 column as varchar. I changed to ms jdbc driver and solved the problem